# How to order the table data with double condition order in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table like this :

```
+-------------+------------+
+    my_id    +    name    +
+-------------+------------+
+      1      +    Adam    +
+-------------+------------+
+      2      +    Udin    +
+-------------+------------+
+      3      +    Asep    +
+-------------+------------+
+      4      +   Jarwo    +
+-------------+------------+
+      5      +  Bambang   +
+-------------+------------+
```

And then I wanna show just my data have a newest id and limit my data until 3 row, like this :

```
+-------------+------------+
+    my_id    +    name    +
+-------------+------------+
+      5      +   Bambang  +
+-------------+------------+
+      4      +   Jarwo    +
+-------------+------------+
+      3      +   Asep     +
+-------------+------------+
```

For the problem is I wanna order again my data into ascending by name field, and when I insert a query for order by after sorting my id by descending is not working and my data is not sorting by name, for my query code like this :

```
SELECT tables.my_id, tables.name
FROM tables
ORDER BY tables.my_id DESC, tables.name ASC
LIMIT 3
```

And for the result still same with my code when I sorting my id by descending, and my expectation like this :

```
+-------------+------------+
+    my_id    +    name    +
+-------------+------------+
+      3      +    Asep    +
+-------------+------------+
+      5      +   Bambang  +
+-------------+------------+
+      4      +   Jarwo    +
+-------------+------------+
```

so what's wrong with my code? Thanks before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The alias "tables" is not defined
2. tables.my_id + 0; Does nothing
3. What I understand ID is unique; So second sort will not work

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT my_id, tables.name
  FROM occupants
  ORDER BY my_id DESC
  LIMIT 3
) t
ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

Comment: sorry sir for make you miss understanding with my question, I already edit my question, and thanks for the feedback I will try to my code first

Comment: @LuckALip I think you do not understand how sort works in case of multiple columns; If you sort by my_id then name what happens is only names with same my_id will be sorted

Comment: @LuckALip we can discuss this if you still do not understand

Comment: How and where sir?

Comment: @LuckALip: Your problem is not sorting by multiple columns. Sorting by multiple columns could look like this: `order by name, id`, which means: order by name first and for rows with the same name order these further by id. Your problem is that you want to limit by one sort order and show the results by another sort order. Unfortunately, this is only possible in two steps as shown: Order by one sort key and apply `LIMIT`. Then select from this result and order by the other sort key.

Comment: yes sir, I think that can be solve with one condition after sorting my id, and then sorting again with my name. And for your explain it is right, I can't make my query like that, and first thing is how can I orderby  my id with `limit`, and when I got my result I must sorting again with my name (from the result of sorting my id and giving the `limit`), thank you sir